# Error importing scipy in ipython notebook

Tags: python, import, scipy, ipython

I am able to import scipy and libraries that call scipy in spyder, but I am not able to when I am in an ipython notebook. I'm running Windows 8 and have installed the latest version of Anaconda. I have attached 2 images that display the types of errors that I'm getting.

[image: Trying to import the signal library from scipy]

[image: Import scipy first and then try to import signal library and get a new error]

Comment: Part of your `scipy` module is not built correctly. What `Python` distribution are you using? `Anaconda`?

Comment: Python 2.7; Anaconda2